# Which- on two vectors of unequal length?

Tags: r

I have two vectors of unequal length, a and b with length(a) being less than b.

I would like to find the indices in 'a' which contain the values in intersect(a,b). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
a <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- list(6,2,1,5,7,9,10)
```

And you want to identify the position of elements of `a` in `b`, use:

```
which(a %in% b)
# [1] 1 2 5
```

This also works if `a` and `b` are vectors, e.g. `a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)` and `b <- c(6,2,1,5,7,9,10)`

Comment: I think `a` and `b` are meant to be vectors. Although the solution would work for both. (+1).

Comment: Only if you are arguing (as you could if you were feeling disputatious) that `list(1,2,3)` is a vector. That is not what most people call a 'vector' in "casual conversation".